# Does enabling dhcp stops broadcasting within the network (currently on static)?

Tags: routing, dhcp, multicast

I have recently found the broadcasting in a network which is running on static IP's. If I enable DHCP will the broadcasting stops?
Which is the best way to prevent broadcasting?

Comment: What would be the need, or desire, for reducing the minimum amount of congestion that this produces?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

DHCP will add more broadcast on your network.

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

A layer-2 network depends on broadcasts in order to function. The way one host discovers the layer-2 address of another host (including the gateway) on the same network is by using ARP to resolve the layer-3 address to the layer-2 address. ARP sends a broadcast since it doesn't know the layer-2 address (what it is looking for).

Broadcasts are an essential part of networking, and preventing broadcasts will kill your network.

Answer (score 0):

With DHCP you can set flags for Windows hosts to never use brodcasts to find each other. This way you could potentially have less broadcasts, but...

you need to check with network analyzer like tcpdump or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see which machines are broadcasting what. Then you can turn off protocols and/or applications which are causing this and are not needed. Also if you have smart switch you could enable protocol vlans to limit protocol broadcasts only to proper hosts, etc.